# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object error when using fullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, laravel, fullcalendar

I'm trying to create a FullCalendar in laravel project
and get this error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at entries (<anonymous>)
    at e (jquery.min.js:4:7727)
    at Ab (jquery.min.js:4:7608)
    at Ab (jquery.min.js:4:7631)
    at Ab (jquery.min.js:4:7631)
    at Function.r.param (jquery.min.js:4:7918)
    at Function.ajax (jquery.min.js:4:12227)
    at Et.e.constructor.select (MyReservations:121:27)
    at constructor.publiclyTrigger (fullcalendar.min.js:9:16482)
    at Et.e.constructor.publiclyTrigger (fullcalendar.min.js:8:30673)
```

Here is My blade

**MyReservations.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>My Reservations</title>
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>




<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" style="text-transform: capitalize" id="ResModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add New Reservation</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <!-- Room -->
                <select class="form-control" aria-label="Default select example" name="room_id" id="room_id" >
                    <option selected>Select Room</option>
                    @foreach($room as $items)
                        <option value="{{$items->id}}">{{$items->id}}</option>
                    @endforeach

                </select>
                <br>
                <!--  Title -->


                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-text"> Title : </span>
                    <input class="form-control" aria-label="Title" name="title" id="title"></input>

                </div>
                <br>
                <!-- Objectif -->
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-text">Objectif :</span>
                    <textarea class="form-control" aria-label="Objectif" name="objectif" id="objectif"></textarea>
                </div>
             




            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <h3 class="text-center mt-5">My Reservations</h3>
            <div class="col-md-11 offset-1 mt-5 mb-5">

                <div id="calendar">

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {

            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });

            var reservation = @json($events);
           $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                editable:true,
                header:{
                    left:'prev,next today',
                    center:'title',
                    right:'month, agendaWeek, agendaDay'
                },
                events: reservation,
                selectable:true,
                selectHelper:true,
                select: function(start, end, allDay)
                {
                    $('#ResModal').modal('toggle');
                    $('#submit').click(function () {
                        var title =$('#title').val;
                        var start = moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                        var end = moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                        var objectif =$('#objectif').val;
                        var room_id =$('#room_id').val;


                    });

                        $.ajax({
                            url:"{{route('MyReservations.store')}}",
                            type:"POST",
                            data:{title, start, end, room_id, objectif},
                            success:function(response)
                            {
                               // MyReservations.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                               // alert("Added Successfully");
                                console.log(response)

                         },

                        })

                },

            });
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my controller

**MyController**

```
 public function  index(){

        $events=array();
        $reservations = reservation::all();
        foreach ($reservations as $reservation){
            $events[] = [
                'title' =>$reservation->title,
                'start' =>$reservation->start,
                'end' =>$reservation->end,

//
//                'objectif' =>$reservation->objectif,
//                'room_id' =>$reservation->room_id,
//                'user_id' =>$reservation->user_id,
//                'stat' =>$reservation->stat,


            ];
        }
         $room=room::all();
        return view('/MyReservations', ['events'=>$events],compact('room'));
    }




    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'title' =>'required|string',
            'objectif' =>'required|string',
            'room_id' =>'required',



        ]);
        $reservation =reservation::create ([
            'objectif' => $request->objectif,
            'start' => $request->start,
            'end' => $request->end,
            'stat' => $request->stat,
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'room_id' => $request->room_id,
        ]);
        return response()->json($reservation);

    }
```

i'm a beginner and i was follwing a tutorial when I click on a square of the calendar, it shows the bootstrap model (till here everything is fine) once I click on ' save changes' i get this problem I think the problem starts at $.ajax, and the store function in MyController

i don't really know where is the problem i was watching a tutorial and i did exactly the same

Note : My model continues **$fillable**
And i Have three tables ( users , reservations and rooms )

Comment: Any particular reason why you're starting with such an old version of fullCalendar? Anyway, when does the error occur? is it at soon as you load the page and the calendar? Does it show anything on the screen at all for the calendar, or just a blank space?

Comment: Also can you show a sample of your event JSON? At a guess the issue might be most likely due to some missing data in one or more fields of an event.

Comment: Hello , i didn't know it was an old version fullCalendar i'm a beginner and i was follwing a tutorial 
when I click on a square of the calendar, it shows the bootstrap model (till here everything is fine) once I click on ' save changes' i get this problem I think the problem starts at $.ajax, and the store function in MyController

Comment: Sir, I don't know where to find the JSON event! as I told you, sir, I was following a tutorial and this is all that I wrote (blade.php, controller, reservation model, and web)

Comment: i think the store function is not working at all , the validations are not even working ! i mean at least it shouldn't allow me to leave any field empty , but it is not working this part : 
` $request->validate([
            'title' =>'required|string',
            'objectif' =>'required|string',
            'room_id' =>'required',
        ]); `

Comment: `I don't know where to find the JSON event`...well you're outputting into the JavaScript as the result of `@json($events);`, so I expect if you look in the generated source code of your page (you can do this using your browser's View Source feature) you'll what data has been inserted there instead of the command.

Comment: `once I click on ' save changes`...ah ok then, it wuld have been good to have that description in your question to begin with, it helps us narrow down the problem a bit. You should [edit] the question to include important info like that, rather than hiding it in the comments :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think basically the issue is that the `$.ajax({` command needs to be inside the `$('#submit').click(function () { ... })` area. Otherwise it'll run the AJAX command as soon as the selection is made without waiting for the user to enter anything or submit the form.

So that means the variables declared inside that `click` area, which the AJAX is trying to rely on, won't exist yet, and that would explain the error about "undefined" variables.

It should look like this instead:

```
select: function(start, end, allDay)
{
  $('#ResModal').modal('toggle');  
  $('#submit').off("click");

  $('#submit').on("click", function () {
    var title = $('#title').val;
    var start = moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    var end = moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    var objectif = $('#objectif').val;
    var room_id = $('#room_id').val;

    $.ajax({
      url:"{{route('MyReservations.store')}}",
      type:"POST",
      data:{title, start, end, room_id, objectif},
      success:function(response)
      {
        // MyReservations.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
        // alert("Added Successfully");
        console.log(response)
      },
    })
  });
}
```

Note that I also modified the "click" handler slightly and added an `.off` call just before it. That's so that if you then select another area afterwards, and then another one, it doesn't add more and more "click" handlers without removing the previous ones - because if you didn't remove them, then when the modal is submitted it will run all the added handlers (one for each time there's a selection) and re-submit the earlier event data to the server, resulting in duplicate data being stored.